# Grafana - use custom variable as regex in query

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

we have prometheus datasource and I’m stuck at trying to use custom variable with few values as comma separated values, I wanted to use it to replace as regex in the label_values(job=~$"{eks_cluster:regex}"), but i get the error templating variables could not be initialized.
Following are the screenshots to show what I’m trying to achieve
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `eks_cluster` variable. This will just as much not work if the query is simply `label_values(job=~".")`

The `label_values` query, [as described in Grafana documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable), takes either a label name or a label name and a metric name. It does not take a match to do whatever you wanted it to do. If you want to filter the values returned, use the Regex field just below Query.